# PostSharp Express asking for license

Tags: postsharp

I have an assembly with a number of aspects created using PostSharp express.   On my build server, I was getting warnings about conflicting aspects, so I decided to add the following attributes to the Aspects to enforce ordering:

```
    [ProvideAspectRole(StandardRoles.ExceptionHandling)]
    [AspectRoleDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Order, AspectDependencyPosition.After, StandardRoles.Caching)]
```

I did this, checked in and built the code on the server and everything worked great.  The warnings were gone!   However, when another developer got latest, he was unable to compile on his local machine.   On his machine PostSharp felt that the express license was not valid for those aspects.

Are those aspect attributes limited to the Pro version of PostSharp?   And if so, why is it able to compile on my machine and the build server using an express license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AspectRoleDependency is a Pro feature.

Licensing is not enforced on build servers, so you always get all features enabled on build servers irrespective of the license registered on your development workstation.